# listening file changes in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a text file with two lines with `on/off` and `continue/finish` which are settled by another program. A VBA program must wait or proceed depending the string value in the first line and stop listening events if the second line is `finish`. I've read that one can make a variable with a Class and event in order to listen changes, no problem if the variable is defined in the same program and changed during the runtime. But how to listen if a string has changed in a external file and get its value? is it possible? Must I check if the file has changed and then get the lines? A pair of code lines will be helpful, thanks man.

Comment: Have you got any code already or are you looking for someone to do your homework for you?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing in VBA I could think of is to add repeated file look up as read the file every few seconds. So check in VBA help the command `Application.OnTime`. If your application is not doing a lot in between it might work or you. There is a possibility of a small hanger each time the code runs.

As well, have a look at `FileSystemObject`. In order to use it, you need to add a reference in VBA to `\Windows\System32\scrrun.dll`. At least there are some useful functions to Access files efficiently.

Hope this guides you in the right direction.

Comment: I was thinking similar to you, I'm trying this [link] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zds3tce6(v=vs.80).aspx) but System.IO.FileInfo is causing compilation stops, despite I've added the reference (by using the menu) to scrrun.dll  as you suggested. The idea is, that the string value, i.e. the time of file modification,  is updated by Windows and my program is listening that, then certain task will be done immediately. My VBA is controlling step motors, they must relocate the sample when detectors write `off` in the text file.

Comment: Wait, the link above is VB.net (in Visual Studio) and not VBA (Visual Basic for Application). That is a different programming language. The link above is the proper way to do it in VB.net. As far as I know, in VBA you can not listen to file changes unlike in .net. When you read the file as I suggested in VBA, make sure you open the file in ReadOnly mode in case both System accessing the file and as well, add an error handling. Here is a sample [link]http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?view=article&id=103

Comment: JoeCoolman, did you find a solution? Could I help you on this?

Comment: Nop, I didn't find a solution yet, instead a workaround only. Yeah you @Rolfi are welcome to make contributions. What I did is to check the text file lines periodically, doing so makes the program unable to perform any other task until *finish* is read. By now, this workaround is ok for me but it would be great that the program could do other tasks while is listening changes in a text file contents.